# How to encrypt a text file in a portable manner based solely on a password?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl

I used to use openssl aes-256-cbc, but the problem I have with this is when I try to decrypt in a different version of the distro it fails, as if it depends also on some internal key or something, instead of depending solely on the password. So I have to keep a different encrypted file for each version of the distro, which is annoying and bad.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Some Linux utilities that encrypt using only one password and that exist in most
repositories:

**ccrypt**

Installation (one of the below):

```
sudo apt-get install ccrypt
yum install ccrypt
```

Usage:

```
ccencrypt path-to-file            (creates a .cpt file)
ccdecrypt path-to-cpt-file        (creates the original file)
```

**Zip**

Installation (one of the below):

```
sudo apt-get install zip
yum install zip
```

Usage:

```
zip --password mypassword result.zip list-of-files
unzip result.zip
```